# Using shouldChangeCharactersInRange to limit characters entered, but cannot detect return

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm using the following code in my `UITextField` delegate to limit the characters that can be entered:

FYI: The `UITextField` outlet is called `nameChoiceField`. Plus there is a label outlet called `errorMessageLabel`.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSString *potentialNewChosenName = [self.nameChoiceField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSCharacterSet *nonLettersNumbersOrDashes = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890- "] invertedSet];

    if ([potentialNewChosenName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonLettersNumbersOrDashes].length != potentialNewChosenName.length) {
        self.errorMessageLabel.text = @"Only letters, numbers etc allowed.";
        return NO;
    } else {
        self.errorMessageLabel.text = @"That's okay.";
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Which works nicely (so long as autocorrect is off, and if you add some other stuff in to stop the auto full stop after you enter 2 spaces).

However! When you tap `return` on the keyboard, it doesn't allow it (displaying the error message "Only letters....").

How do you restrict the input a user can make, and still have the `return` button to be recognised?

Also, are there any best practices for recognising the `delete` button that should be implemented above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that:

return is represented by a `string` of `@"\n"`

delete is represented by a `string` of `@""` (with the length of the `range` determining how much gets deleted).